# Content Search web part costomization: remove the document icon from the 2 lines

Tags: sharepoint-online, display-template, content-search-web-part, formatting

[image]

I have removed the document icon but the line looks 'indented', does anybody know what code I need to touch to have the text in line with the box border on the left?

I would like a code that can be placed in the html of the display template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it, it's the cbs-detail

```
            <div class="cbs-Detail" id="_#= dataContainerId =#_" style="margin-left: 0px;">
```